# Carathéodory's theorem for $SO(3)$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, matrices, convexity

Let $Q \in \operatorname{Conv} SO(3)$.

Is there a way to retrieve an explicit representation of $Q$ as convex combination $Q=\sum_{k=1}^{r}{\lambda_{i}R_{i}}, 
R_{i} \in SO(3)$?

An approximation can also be useful.

Answer (score 3):

A closely related answer: The convex hull of SO(n) is studied in [this paper](http://faculty.washington.edu/jamesfs/sonfiles/SPW_son.pdf) by Saunderson, Parrilo, and Willsky (2015). In particular, that paper proves that this convex hull is doubly spectrahedral, and provides explicit representations. For $n=3$, see (1.11) in the paper.

Comment: That's where I'm coming from :):):). I'm relaxing a SO(3) optimization problem using their representation and get something in Conv SO(3). But I still need to obtain an answer in SO(3) so I thought I'd try to decompose the "something" into SO(3) "bits" and use one of the bits as the final answer or at least as starting points for local search.

Comment: I guess, that's why it is good to add context to the question when asking it, to avoid answers like mine :-)